# How to convert typed dependency to semantic graph

Tags: stanford-nlp

I've retrieved TypedDependency from tree annotation. Now I want to get the graph structure of the dependencies instead of the original list structure. The SemanticGraphEdge class contains four IndexedWord variables which are source, target, gov and dep, also there is a weight variable. How should I determine these variables from a TypedDependency class? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TypedDependency tp;
SemanticGraph semgraph = new SemanticGraph(td);
```